I am trying to install appium driver uiautomator2 but getting error. Can anyone help me out in this?
× Installing 'uiautomator2' using NPM install spec 'appium-uiautomator2-driver'
Error: × Encountered an error when installing package: npm command 'install --save-dev --no-progress --no-audit --omit=peer --save-exact --global-style --no-package-lock appium-uiautomator2-driver --json' failed with code 1.
I tried changing the appium version, nodejs version.
Appium v2.4.1
node v16.20.2
npm v8.19.4

Please surround the error with code-quote, so we can see it more clear. Also please mention the exact command you use for installing appium.
